# Undefined variable in custom Drupal module

Tags: php, module, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I write custom Drupal module. Want show field_myear in contents. With the following:

```
<div class="right">
                                <h4>'.$m_detail->title.'</h4>
                                <div class="section">'.$field_myear.'</div>
                                <div class="description">
                                    <div
```

But when refresh page, get this error:

```
Notice: theme_news()/home/domains/site.net/public_html/sites/all/modules/site/theme.module dosyasının 1247 satırı) içinde Undefined variable: field_myear.
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the execution of your page. Step through it line by line. When you are outputting the HTML shown above, you haven't got a value set for `field_myear`. You need to be sure you are setting it prior to trying to output it - or you need to check your variable name to make certain that it is correct and doesn't have a typo in it.